# Why does my Zorki 4 take blurred pics on infinity focus?

Tags: troubleshooting, focus, old-cameras, rangefinder, infinity-focus

I've recently bought a Zorki 4 and the results I get from my test roll are quite disappointing.
I've been calibrating the mirror, adjusting it for both infinity focus and close one (1 meter).
Here is the result I get for a picture taken with the focus set to infinity on the lens. As you see, the picture is blurred and it seems that only the close part of it is quite neat (bottom of the pic).

Would anyone have any explanation for that and how to fix it? I don't really get how this is possible as even if the calibration setting was not accurate, it would be some close distance pictures that would be blurred (which is not the case).

Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: Is the lens meant for the Zorki? Was the lens adapted from another camera mount? Losing the ability to focus at infinity is exactly what happens when you put additional space between the lens and the body (i.e., extension tubes or bellows). If the lens was adapted, and the adaptation didn't match Zorki's flange focus distance correctly, you effectively have a lens with a built-in small extension tube, unable to focus at infinity.

Comment: How are you adjusting the mirror/rangefinder? Also, see: The [rangefinderforum.com's Zorki 4K How to CLA](http://www.rangefinderforum.com/forums/showpost.php?p=453103&postcount=11) thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the infinity stops on the lens so the rear element goes closer to the image plane. Adapted lenses have this problem and most adaptors with correction elements Destroy image quality.